# Aggregate Groups in Pandas by highest value from column group

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.10 with Pandas 1.3.4

Using the following code I create a dataframe, and then sort it to "group" the `Id's` together, and only display each unique `Id` one time.

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['123', '228', '358', '123', '358', '358','433','496', '496', '496'],
         ['James Smith', 'John Smith', 'John Smith', 'Johnny Smith', 'Jonathan Smith', 'John B. Smith', 'Jon Smithson', 'John Smythe','John Smith', 'John A. Smithy'],
         [0.56, 0.98, 1.0, 0.65, 0.77, 1.0, 0.80, 0.97, 1.0, 0.99],
         ['AM', 'WL','WL', 'PP', 'PP', 'AM', 'AM', 'WL', 'WL', 'PP']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('Id', 'Name', 'Score', 'Dept'))
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df = df.sort_values('Id')
df
```

Which yields:

[image]

Now I need to take this a step further, and display a dataframe which:

> 1. Gets the highest score from each group.
> 2. Using that list of highest scores from each group, sort the groups in descending order.
> 3. If two groups' highest scores are identical, then sort by `Id` in ascending order.
> 4. Create a new column 0 called "Highest Score" which displays that highest score from that group - display each highest score value only once per group, similar to `Id`.
> 5. Each group's set of scores should also be sorted in descending order.

So it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using `set_index` to append the highest score per group, calculated with `transform` and `max`. then `reorder_levels` of the index as wanted, and `sort_values`, specifying ascending False or True for each level.

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index(df.reset_index('Score').groupby('Id')
                   ['Score'].transform(max).rename('Highest_Score'), 
                 append=True)
      .reorder_levels(['Highest_Score'] + df.index.names)
      .sort_values(['Highest_Score','Id','Score'], ascending=[False,True,False])
)
```

Comment: Wow you nailed it.  Nicely done, and thank you for the explanation.  I knew Pandas could do this in just a few lines of code. :)